# Prove if $f,g\in BV[a,b]$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ prove $\alpha f+\beta g\in BV[a,b].$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $BV[a,b]$ be collection of all bounded variation real function on $[a,b]$.
If $f,g\in BV[a,b]$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ prove
$$\alpha f+\beta g\in BV[a,b].$$

I try as below.

Given $f,g\in BV[a,b]$ then
$$
V(f,[a,b])=\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\vert\leq M_1
$$
and
$$
V(g,[a,b])=\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1})\vert\leq M_2.
$$
I want to prove $$\alpha f+\beta g\in BV[a,b],$$
i.e.
$$
V(\alpha f+\beta g,[a,b])=\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert (\alpha f+\beta g)(x_k)-(\alpha f+\beta g)(x_{k-1})\vert\leq M.
$$
Is it right the prove as follows?
\begin{align}
V(\alpha f+\beta g,[a,b])&=\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert (\alpha f+\beta g)(x_k)-(\alpha f+\beta g)(x_{k-1})\vert\\
&= \sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert \alpha f(x_k)+\beta g(x_k)-\alpha f(x_{k-1})-\beta g(x_{k-1})\vert\\
&= \sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert \alpha (f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))+\beta (g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1}))\vert\\
&\leq \alpha\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert  (f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))\vert+\beta\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \vert(g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1}))\vert\\
&= \alpha M_1+\beta M_2\\
&= M
\end{align}

**EDIT**
\begin{align}
V(\alpha f+\beta g,[a,b])&=\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert (\alpha f+\beta g)(x_k)-(\alpha f+\beta g)(x_{k-1})\vert\\
&= \sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert \alpha f(x_k)+\beta g(x_k)-\alpha f(x_{k-1})-\beta g(x_{k-1})\vert\\
&= \sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert \alpha (f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))+\beta (g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1}))\vert\\
&\leq \vert\alpha\vert\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\vert  (f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))\vert+\vert\beta\vert\sup \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \vert(g(x_k)-g(x_{k-1}))\vert\\
&= \vert\alpha\vert M_1+\vert\beta\vert M_2\\
&= M
\end{align}

Comment: It is correct if you replace $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by their absolute values at the end of the proof.

Comment: Please see my edited question. Is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure why $(\alpha f+\beta g)(x_k)=\alpha f(x_k)+\beta g(x_k)$.

Comment: It is correct now.